# to update one table by matching all columns of another table

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I need to update one column of a table, TA, based on another table, TB, which has less number of columns than TA.

Say TA has 27 columns, `A,B,...,Z,status,` TB has 26 columns, `A,B,...,Z`. I want to update TA as follows.

```
update TA set TA.status=1 
from TA, TB 
where TA.A=TB.A,..., TA.Z=TB.Z
```

Note values should be considered equal if both are null. What's an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target table should not be included in the FROM clause of an UPDATE statement.

As you also want to treat two NULL values as equal, you need to use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` rather than `=`. And you can simplify the condition by using a record notation:

```
update ta
   set status = 1
from tb
where (ta.a, ta.b, ta.c, ta.d, ...) is not distinct from (tb.a, tb.b, tb.c, tb.d, ...);
```